How to configure Freeradius weekly reset on a day other than Sunday?
I'm running FreeRADIUS 3.0.20 and it works fine. In the sqlcounter module, I'm using hourly, daily, weekly, monthly counters. I understand that a hourly counter resets at 0 minutes, and a daily counter resets at midnight, but I have a problem with the weekly counter resetting on Sundays.
The reason is that my system is being used by a group of people with a weekly turnover, which never occurs on Sundays, and they asked to configure the week day for the weekly reset counter.
Is it possible?
This is my weekly counter for session time:
sqlcounter weeklycounter {
    sql_module_instance = sql
    dialect = ${modules.sql.dialect}
    counter_name = Weekly-Session-Time
    check_name = Max-Weekly-Session
    reply_name = Session-Timeout
    key = User-Name
    reset = weekly
    query = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(acctsessiontime - \
                 GREATEST((%%b - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(acctstarttime)), 0)), 0) \
                 FROM radacct WHERE username = '%{${key}}' AND \
                 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(acctstarttime) + acctsessiontime > '%%b'"
}


Maybe I found the answer on the Freeradius source code here https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/master/src/modules/rlm_sqlcounter/rlm_sqlcounter.c : on line 164, function find_next_reset() computes the next weekly reset like this:
tm->tm_mday += (7 - tm->tm_wday) +(7*(num-1));
This code clearly moves tm_mday forward to the next Sunday (7 - tm->tm_wday).
A simple improvement could allow to move it forward to the next given 'targetWeekday':
tm->tm_mday += ((7 - tm->tm_wday + targetWeekday) % 7) +(7*(num-1));
Any chance to have this improvement in the future?
